# how can i pass project_id to stage form on project show page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a scaffold project and other scaffold as stage. i have added a stage form button on show page of the project. now i want to pass id of each project into stage how can i do that in rails? i have many to one association between stage and project.

routes.rb

```
  resources :stages
  resources :projects
  root to: 'home#index'
```

projects_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  end

  def show
    @stages = Stage.all
  end
  def new
    @project = current_user.projects.build
  end
```

project show.html.erb

```
  <%= link_to "Add Stage", new_stage_path, :class=>"button primary small" %>
```

model project.rb

```
  has_many :stages
```

model project.rb

```
belongs_to :project
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing that would be using the [nested routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

***routes.rb***

```
resources :projects do
  resources :stages
end
```

This will create the routes something like this:

```
project_stages      GET          /projects/:project_id/stages(.:format)             stages#index
                    POST         /projects/:project_id/stages(.:format)             stages#create
new_project_stage   GET          /projects/:project_id/stages/new(.:format)         stages#new
edit_project_stage  GET          /projects/:project_id/stages/:id/edit(.:format)    stages#edit
project_stage       GET          /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)         stages#show
                    PATCH        /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)         stages#update
                    PUT          /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)         stages#update
                    DELETE       /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)         stages#destroy
```

***show.html.erb***

```
<%= link_to "Add Stage", new_project_stage(@project), :class=>"button primary small" %>
```

***stages_controller.rb***

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @stage = @project.stages.build(stages_params)
  @stage.save
end
```

So here we have added nested resource because the stage belongs to the project. This way we will get the project always on which we are adding the stage instead of sending that manually.

Comment: i am not able to render show.html.erb getting no method error

Comment: @Anuj Did you restart your server after redefining the new routes?

Comment: undefined method `stages_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f2e5d24f4e0>:0x00007f2e5c94d838>

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes i restarted but getting same error.

Comment: The `stages_path` has changed now to `project_stages_path(@project)` that is why it is giving exception. Please have a read of the Rails documentation to get a better idea

Answer (score 0):

it can be fixed easily by passing the project_id into your form path.

```
<%= link_to "Add Stage", new_stage_path(project_id: @project.id), :class=>"button primary small" %>
```

then in your stages_controller.rb

```
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @stage = @project.stages.build
end
```

while in the projects_controller.rb

```
def show
  @project=Project.find(params[:id])
  @stages = Stage.all
end
```

HOWEVER,
I strongly suggest that you should implement your association using [Nested Resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)
 for easy of development and maintenance.

Comment: not able to set project_id in database for every stage

Comment: @project needs to be set in the show-method. Try this updated codes

Comment: now i am getting undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Which one is nil?

Comment: <% if stage.errors.any? %> errors showing nil in stages new form. NoMethodError in Stages#new

Comment: You need to work on your stages_controller.rb. I already helped you with the passing of the project_id. provide '@stage = @project.stages.build' in your stages#new-method

Comment: after create @stage =Stage.new in new method. still i am getting undefined method `stages_path' for error